# как установить vkbottle 3 версии?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

как установить библиотеку vk bottle именно 3 версии?

Comment: pip install <модуль>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip install vkbottle==3.x Вместо х более точна версия

Comment: спасибо, через 3 минуты сделаю лучшим ответом